# How to resolve: files which are visible in Terminal, but invisible in the Finder?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, skype

In Yosemite v10.10.3, I am trying to reinstall Skype, as it does not sign-in at all, following this [link](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12073/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-and-then-reinstall-skype-for-mac-os-x). In order to do so, I need to move some files and folders to trash as to totally uninstall Skype first. However, I cannot see these files and folders in the Finder, although they are visible in the Terminal !!

I've also tried the following two commands:

```
:...& defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
:...& killall Finder
```

The result is that I see many hidden files among which I cannot find the files and folders I am looking for.

Please help me with any of them: Skype sign-in problem or Finder Invisibility !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you aren't looking in the root library, but your user library. Skype in Application Support and com.skype.plist are not invisible by default. Try changing the `~/Library/Application Support` with `/Users/<username>/Library/ Application Support`, with  being your Username without the <>.

I find it easy to "Go to" with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> while there is Finder selected, and in the path type `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/` and click Go. Then look for Skype. To find the plist, do the same, but with Preferences.

Also note that in terminal, the path to Application support would have a backslash (`/Application\ Support`), instead of only a Space

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are correct. I was looking inside the "Root" directory and not inside "Users" directory. The shortcut is very helpful too (a non related question: how did you insert the keyboard keys in your answer?!).

Comment: I used the kbd tags. Like so: `<kbd>Command</kbd>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your sign-in problem but about removing the files, you can remove all the required files from the Terminal itself. Removing the Skype app itself from the Applications folder shouldn't be a problem. Type these in Terminal to remove the other files (press enter after each line to execute the command):

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/
rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.skype.skype.plist*
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used these commands eventually to remove the files you mentioned, well, without the `-f` or `-rf` options. I also typed `~/.Trash/` at the end of the command line to move it to trash first before completely deleting it (just as a security practice). Nonetheless, I am looking to resolve the issue of the visibility in the Finder in case it happened in the future.

Comment: The `-r` option is required for removing directories.
By the way, typing `~/.Trash/` will cause the command to remove this too. It doesn't mean moving it to the Trash.

Comment: And for the visibility of hidden files, I suppose you typed the command wrong, just type these and it will work:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`

then this, 

`killall Finder`

For undoing it, just replace YES with NO.